# Parsing Youtube playlist to Listview

Tags: android, youtube

I'm trying to **get Youtube playlist** and show it in a listview 
I'm using [this tutorial](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/) , it's working fine with me for getting videos **from USERNAME** but when I try to get videos informations **from Playlist** link it shows the following error :

```
Thread-968| Feck
org.json.JSONException: No value for player
org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:569)
com.blundell.tut.service.task.GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.run(GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.java:90)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)


line 90 in GetYouTubeUserVideos is:
       url=jsonObject.getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
```

and I've changed

```
String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
```

to

```
String title = jsonObject.getJSONObject("video").getString("title");
```

and I'm using the following link for playlist :

"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" + username + "?&v=2&alt=jsonc"

Comment: please use code formating, and i think your post needs some more informations about the issue you are facing (maybe more code related to it) thanks

Comment: Only I want to get youtube playlist and show it as listview  
that tutorial shows how to get youtube USER videos , but playlist not working , when I changed JSON link to get data from playlist ,that error shown

Comment: What JSON response do you get? Type the url into your browser to see. for my username I get "playlist not found"

Comment: @Blundell 
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL5ErH2bHcHAmXgk-x3VoaKKOTJuE9tt17?&v=2&alt=jsonc

playlistID instead of username

Answer (score 0):

If you put the JSON through a formatter it is much easier to work with:

```
{
   "apiVersion":"2.1",
   "data":{
      "id":"PL5ErH2bHcHAmXgk-x3VoaKKOTJuE9tt17",
      "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
      "title":"مقاطع افلام كوميدي",
      "description":"",
      "thumbnail":{
         "sqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/I0zWtr2TTFQ/default.jpg",
         "hqDefault":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/I0zWtr2TTFQ/hqdefault.jpg"
      },
      "content":{
         "5":"http://www.youtube.com/p/PL5ErH2bHcHAmXgk-x3VoaKKOTJuE9tt17"
      },
      "totalItems":12,
      "startIndex":1,
      "itemsPerPage":25,
      "items":[
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDmRK1wKF_sUWed67r02_4tE",
            "position":1,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"I0zWtr2TTFQ",
               "uploaded":"2012-10-18T13:42:37.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-30T16:10:44.000Z",
               "uploader":"kgental1",
               "category":"Comedy",
               "title":"اجمل مشهد كوميدي من فيلم رمضان مبروك ابو العلمين حمودة",
               "description":"http://www.facebook.com/Khaled.133\nاجمل مشهد كوميدي من فيلم رمضان مبروك ابو العلمين حمودة",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/I0zWtr2TTFQ/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/I0zWtr2TTFQ/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0zWtr2TTFQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=I0zWtr2TTFQ"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/I0zWtr2TTFQ?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v6.cache6.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlUTJO9ttZMIxMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v6.cache6.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlUTJO9ttZMIxMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":186,
               "rating":5.0,
               "likeCount":"28",
               "ratingCount":28,
               "viewCount":15448,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":6,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDnXYTVmiMufrzGxcLGdEPTg",
            "position":2,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"Ahp8T2J21Ss",
               "uploaded":"2013-01-09T16:19:39.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-22T09:34:44.000Z",
               "uploader":"entertainmenttttmisc",
               "category":"Entertainment",
               "title":"احمد حلمى اجمد مشهد فيلم عسل اسود",
               "description":"",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/Ahp8T2J21Ss/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/Ahp8T2J21Ss/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahp8T2J21Ss&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=Ahp8T2J21Ss"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/Ahp8T2J21Ss?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAkr1XZiT3waAhMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAkr1XZiT3waAhMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":157,
               "aspectRatio":"widescreen",
               "rating":4.571429,
               "likeCount":"25",
               "ratingCount":28,
               "viewCount":7970,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":0,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDv6MEmO1c5QHUzvKie5gHLQ",
            "position":3,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"QChOxhhoTps",
               "uploaded":"2012-12-17T17:00:43.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-28T02:14:16.000Z",
               "uploader":"4tYsmt6tPDd0HjeRftVpxA",
               "category":"Entertainment",
               "title":"احلي مشهد  في فيلم اكس لارج احمد حلمي",
               "description":"صبري صبري اوعي يكون الي في بالي\nبسرعة طياراة علي الماركت هات 5 6 7 علب فول و40 بيضة\nاحلي مشهد  في فيلم اكس لارج احمد حلمي",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/QChOxhhoTps/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/QChOxhhoTps/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QChOxhhoTps&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=QChOxhhoTps"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/QChOxhhoTps?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v5.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAmbTmgYxk4oQBMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v5.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAmbTmgYxk4oQBMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":166,
               "rating":4.921875,
               "likeCount":"251",
               "ratingCount":256,
               "viewCount":86896,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":26,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDomehvdMw9jj-9cqapYviAc",
            "position":4,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"4DGuUppbLlI",
               "uploaded":"2011-02-12T09:24:41.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-23T18:14:36.000Z",
               "uploader":"dawafnet",
               "category":"Animals",
               "title":"وش أجرام.flv",
               "description":"",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/4DGuUppbLlI/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/4DGuUppbLlI/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DGuUppbLlI&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=4DGuUppbLlI"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/4DGuUppbLlI?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlSLluaUq4x4BMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v5.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlSLluaUq4x4BMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":60,
               "rating":4.848101,
               "likeCount":"152",
               "ratingCount":158,
               "viewCount":130456,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":20,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDkOZ2Iydoc0s77lPOpTxQWA",
            "position":5,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"bDApYRUHbj4",
               "uploaded":"2007-06-01T15:45:11.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-08-01T16:44:19.000Z",
               "uploader":"hanybee1",
               "category":"Comedy",
               "title":"بحبها يا لمبى",
               "description":"محمد سعد فى فيلم اللى باللى بالك\nتم الرفع بواسطة\n-\n-\n-\n-\nتصميم مواقع\nhttp://hanybee.com/%D8%AA%D8%B5%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%85-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%B9.html- تصميم مواقع - إمتلك موقع بتصميم مثالي و متوافق مع محركات البحث على أفضل السيرفرات العالمية\nhttp://hanybee.com تصميم مواقع\nhttp://q8data.com  إستضافة مواقع",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/bDApYRUHbj4/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/bDApYRUHbj4/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDApYRUHbj4&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=bDApYRUHbj4"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/bDApYRUHbj4?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v3.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAk-bgcVYSkwbBMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v3.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAk-bgcVYSkwbBMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":186,
               "geoCoordinates":{
                  "latitude":26.82055,
                  "longitude":30.8025
               },
               "rating":4.8163857,
               "likeCount":"1642",
               "ratingCount":1721,
               "viewCount":1710657,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":613,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDjPBN-0oC_-K-XQaBCRUBqo",
            "position":6,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"Y5SnuWN9IUA",
               "uploaded":"2010-10-08T22:33:48.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-31T20:16:14.000Z",
               "uploader":"salomiaaa",
               "category":"Comedy",
               "title":"اللى بالى بالك - محمد سعد - صباح الخير يا جريمة",
               "description":"مقطع من فيلم اللى بالى بالك لمحمد سعد\r\nبرنامج صباح الخير يا جريمة و لقاء كوميدى خلف الأسوار",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/Y5SnuWN9IUA/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/Y5SnuWN9IUA/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5SnuWN9IUA&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=Y5SnuWN9IUA"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/Y5SnuWN9IUA?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v2.cache4.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlAIX1juaeUYxMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v2.cache4.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlAIX1juaeUYxMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":122,
               "rating":4.7789474,
               "likeCount":"359",
               "ratingCount":380,
               "viewCount":302642,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":83,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDjpI5y-a4MjSa1YK1BdXQRM",
            "position":7,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"B7ZofpoCERQ",
               "uploaded":"2010-09-24T21:51:15.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-08-01T22:02:54.000Z",
               "uploader":"salehvideo",
               "category":"Comedy",
               "title":"عادل إمام - طموحات محشش ذو خيال واسع",
               "description":"الفنان الكوميدي الكبير عادل امام في مشهد مضحك و أليم جدا من فيلم هالو أمريكا \r\nجلسة غرزة محششين يخبرهم فيها بأحلامه بعد هجرته لأمريكا\r\nالطريف بأن معظم ما جاء في الجلسة تترجم أحلام الكثير من عواطلي عالمنا العرب بعد فشلهم في بناء أنفسهم بأوطانهم\r\n.\r\n.\r\n\r\n.\r\n.\r\nالزعيم عادل امام مصر فيلم عربي كوميدي  الكوميديا الضحك",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/B7ZofpoCERQ/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/B7ZofpoCERQ/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7ZofpoCERQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=B7ZofpoCERQ"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/B7ZofpoCERQ?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v8.cache4.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAkUEQKafmi2BxMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v8.cache4.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAkUEQKafmi2BxMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":202,
               "rating":4.6484427,
               "likeCount":"1318",
               "ratingCount":1445,
               "viewCount":1358295,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":201,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDgCfmctARkNOeM7_TlnchAs",
            "position":8,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"LYEnAYMSm2c",
               "uploaded":"2011-07-27T23:41:34.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-18T00:19:52.000Z",
               "uploader":"samself96",
               "category":"Comedy",
               "title":"علاء ولي الدين - مدرس رياضيات و فرنساوي",
               "description":"مدرس رياضيات و فرنساوي",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/LYEnAYMSm2c/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/LYEnAYMSm2c/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYEnAYMSm2c&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=LYEnAYMSm2c"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/LYEnAYMSm2c?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v4.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlnmxKDASeBLRMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v4.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlnmxKDASeBLRMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":51,
               "rating":4.95,
               "likeCount":"79",
               "ratingCount":80,
               "viewCount":29528,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":7,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDqdCzgih6IgIXgVoeSPGbo8",
            "position":9,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"pyzrIUDqwes",
               "uploaded":"2010-10-10T00:03:36.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-23T15:18:46.000Z",
               "uploader":"802741413",
               "category":"Comedy",
               "title":"شكلك فاهم يا نص.3gp",
               "description":"",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/pyzrIUDqwes/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/pyzrIUDqwes/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pyzrIUDqwes&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=pyzrIUDqwes"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/pyzrIUDqwes?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v5.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAnrwepAIesspxMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v5.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAnrwepAIesspxMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":123,
               "rating":5.0,
               "likeCount":"8",
               "ratingCount":8,
               "viewCount":3512,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":0,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDibx0FpC1_-N4DJ4FC02rm8",
            "position":10,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"CgTPJ8tslhU",
               "uploaded":"2012-09-25T11:41:43.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-31T14:03:29.000Z",
               "uploader":"rp9RStOrjniRvIuHWPs_rw",
               "category":"People",
               "title":"اللمبي في القوات الخاصة سه   سه  مقطع مضحك",
               "description":"لمشاهدة المزيد من الفيديوهات الكوميدية و الافلام الحصرية و المسلسلات و البرامج التلفزيونية \nhttp://www.youtube4u.net\nhttp://www.youtube4u.com\n\n\n\n\nاضحك من قلبك - الضحك اضحكوا اضحكو موت من الضحكة الضحكه ابستم ابتسمى ابتسمي\nكوميديا كوميدي كوميدى جامد موت جامد اخر حاجة حاجه فيديو يوتيوب اليوتيوب الفيديو\nyoutube yotbe مقاطع مضحكة مقطع الفنان الفنانة مسرحية فيلم اضحك \nشاهد مقطع مضحك النجم الممثل المغني المغنى المطرب المطربة المطربه الفنان الفنانه الفنانة",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/CgTPJ8tslhU/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/CgTPJ8tslhU/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgTPJ8tslhU&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=CgTPJ8tslhU"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/CgTPJ8tslhU?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v4.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAkVlmzLJ88EChMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v4.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAkVlmzLJ88EChMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":222,
               "aspectRatio":"widescreen",
               "rating":4.652174,
               "likeCount":"21",
               "ratingCount":23,
               "viewCount":17275,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":2,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDtQAHcmm5pvlDu56XHHglUg",
            "position":11,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"iEWICwJBNzk",
               "uploaded":"2011-05-05T03:59:52.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-31T20:12:08.000Z",
               "uploader":"tahagaba",
               "category":"Comedy",
               "title":"اللمبي يترافع في المحكمة قمة الكوميديا",
               "description":"ابوس ايدك اجل القضية الساعة تسعة tahagaba",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/iEWICwJBNzk/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/iEWICwJBNzk/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEWICwJBNzk&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=iEWICwJBNzk"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/iEWICwJBNzk?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v3.cache6.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAk5N0ECC4hFiBMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v3.cache6.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAk5N0ECC4hFiBMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":208,
               "rating":4.354839,
               "likeCount":"52",
               "ratingCount":62,
               "viewCount":48258,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"denied",
                  "commentVote":"denied",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"PLxzsLIRt--QhyuZ8u3UfqDj3GKbd7lrstCsd3Q30qdvU",
            "position":12,
            "author":"Yer7amJiddak",
            "video":{
               "id":"SbBj6m3KnAY",
               "uploaded":"2013-01-16T11:09:20.000Z",
               "updated":"2013-07-08T14:07:53.000Z",
               "uploader":"fibzchesnais",
               "category":"Sports",
               "title":"\u202bبوشكاش Happy Birthday-Boshkash - Mohamed Saad\u202c\u200e - YouTube.wmv",
               "description":"Happy Birthday-Boshkash - Mohamed Saad",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "sqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SbBj6m3KnAY/default.jpg",
                  "hqDefault":"https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/SbBj6m3KnAY/hqdefault.jpg"
               },
               "player":{
                  "default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbBj6m3KnAY&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
                  "mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=SbBj6m3KnAY"
               },
               "content":{
                  "5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/SbBj6m3KnAY?version=3&f=playlists&app=youtube_gdata",
                  "1":"rtsp://v4.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAkGnMpt6mOwSRMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
                  "6":"rtsp://v4.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAkGnMpt6mOwSRMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
               },
               "duration":283,
               "aspectRatio":"widescreen",
               "rating":5.0,
               "likeCount":"7",
               "ratingCount":7,
               "viewCount":6015,
               "favoriteCount":0,
               "commentCount":1,
               "accessControl":{
                  "comment":"allowed",
                  "commentVote":"allowed",
                  "videoRespond":"moderated",
                  "rate":"allowed",
                  "embed":"allowed",
                  "list":"allowed",
                  "autoPlay":"allowed",
                  "syndicate":"allowed"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The videos are inside an `items` array.

Try something like:

```
JSONArray items = jsonObject.getJsonArray("items");
String url = items.get(0).getJSONObject("player").getString("default");
```

(and if you want more than 1, loop on the JSONArray).

Comment: The method getJSONObject(String) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: `((JSONObject) items.get(0))`